# using vanilla js how do i make the url update

Tags: javascript

how do i make the window.location.url update every 30 seconds to the next id found in the array. Right now i have it alerting hello every few seconds but want the url to change instead

```js
    const myIds=['1_aq4jiqb','1_4u0ocu4u'];

for (let i = 0; i < myIds.length; i++) {
window.location.href = 'https://yahoo.com' + myIds[i]+ '/embed/iframe?';

}
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

```html
<html>


</html>
```

update to the next Id after 30 seconds?

Comment: Once you change the `window.location.href` change you'll loose the script on you page bacause it navigates to the yahoo page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible unless you control each of those sites that you're redirecting to.

When you do `window.location.href =`, an entirely new document is loaded, with (and with only) the JavaScript(s) that new document links to. Anything that happens in your code after a single `window.location.href =` runs will be effectively ignored, because your old JavaScript does not carry over to the newly-loaded page.

Unless you control each of the sites you're redirecting to, the only way to accomplish this (on your browser only) would be to inject JavaScript code of your own into every site with a [userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your're asking, just put the code inside a function, and call that at the `setInterval`.

```js
const myIds=['1_aq4jiqb','1_4u0ocu4u'];

function switchId() {
  for (let i = 0; i < myIds.length; i++) {
    window.location.href = 'https://yahoo.com' + myIds[i]+ '/embed/iframe?';
  }
}

setInterval(function(){ switchId() }, 3000);
```

```html
<html>


</html>
```

Comment: this wont work, see the other answers.

Comment: ids arent switching

Comment: i wonder if i place in an iframe